# IOS implementation advice

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I want to develop an application that stores user's data on an SQL server.
The data contains location and some user note.
I don't want to store anything on the user's iphone.
So what i want to do is an application that gets the user location and check with the server if the location changed for about 100 meters.
I believe this has nothing to do with push notifications.
Am i right? And what do you suggest on how to implement it....
Just Give me an overview of your solution please.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any valid reason why you wouldn't want something stored on the users iphone?  Most of the sandbox data is transparent to the user, and can be deleted if needed.  I'm curious as to why everything 100% must be handled on some external server as this will add A LOT of overhead.

Comment: yes I'm thinking about adding extra notes to the user.
for example i can log into a website and add some extra notifications using google maps to point the location.
if there are any other suggestion or better way. please feel free to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with push notification.

Although, I assume you want to do the same thing than the foursquare application : when you want to checkin, the app sends to the server your actual position, and the server sends back the list of places around, then if you move from a certain distance from your originally point, the app asks the server again for a new list.

So basically, I would just check every 30seconds the position of the user, and if the difference between the last and the current position is above a threshold, just send a request to the server.

Comment: So what if we checked every 30 seconds at the background?
won't this affect the battery life?

Thanks for your response

Comment: Well sure it will, but you can optimize it by stopping the call to the function when you don't need it, and set it back when needed. You can also try different time, like 40s. etc...